# JS Help: While Loop

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

Help:
I am somewhat new to JS and need help with a function.
I need to modify this function to only operate when score < 20,
I would also like to make a variation of this where you row 4 times and then can no longer roll.

```
<html>
<head>
<font face="verdana">
<title>The Game Of Pig</title>
<body background="h.jpg">
<center>
<table border="1">
<script>
alert("Welcome to the Game of Pig!");
function roll() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
function game() {
    var die = document.getElementById("die"),
        score = document.getElementById("score"),
        d,
        d = roll();
    die.innerHTML = d;
    if (d !== 1) {
        score.innerHTML = parseInt(score.innerHTML, 10) + d;
    }
    if (d === 1) {
        score.innerHTML = 0;
    }
} 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<h1>Dice Roll</h1>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div style="width:200px;height:108px;border:4px solid black;">
    <h2>Total: <span id="score">0</span></h2>

    <div>
        <span id="die">0</span>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Roll" id="roll" onclick="game();">  
    </center>
</form>
</body>
</font>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a reason you declare `d` twice?

Answer (score 0):

dont need to parse back the content of the dom elements. use variables in the global scope. they will keep their value between calls to game.

```
var die, score = 0, attempts = 0;
var die_div = document.getElementById("die");
var score_div = document.getElementById("score");

function game() {
  var d = roll();
  if(score + d > 20) return;
  if(attempts > 3) return;    
  die_div.innerHTML = d;
  score =  (d=== 1)?0:(score+d);
  score_div.innerHTML = score;
  attempts++;
}
```

Comment: I tried replacing the script with this code yet it did not work. When pressed, the roll button does nothing.

Comment: just move the <script> tag before the </body> tag. the issue is caused because at the time of the eval of document.getElementByid, the DOM had not been parsed by the browser. check a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/cesarpachon/ku6L60Lq/

Answer (score 0):

```
while (score > 20) {
    // do something
}
```